# Resizing a toplevel window in a class as the parent window resizes

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a class that creates new windows and sticks those windows to the main window, but now I need to figure out how to resize the new windows with the main window.

My issue is that the class I have creates new windows in a way I am not familiar with, so I have no idea how to call on the different `Toplevel` windows that get created in order to change their window size.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('500x500')
        self.drag_id = ''
        self.button_notes = ['tree view 1', 'tree view 2', 'tree view 3', 'tree view 4']
        self.bind('<Configure>', self.dragging)
        # self.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)  # this event that should cause the new
                                               # window to resize
        self.pop_up_list = []
        for ndex, value in enumerate(self.button_notes):
            print(ndex)
            btn = tk.Button(self, text=f'Button {ndex+1}')
            btn.config(command=lambda b=btn, i=ndex: self.toggle_button_pop_ups(i, b))
            btn.grid(row=ndex, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
            self.pop_up_list.append([value, 0, None, btn])

    # def resize(self, e):
    #     p = self.pop_up_list
    #     print("height", e.height, "width", e.width)
    #     p[ndex][2].geometry("100x100") this is the part I need help with

    def dragging(self, event):
        if event.widget is self:
            if self.drag_id == '':
                pass
            else:
                self.after_cancel(self.drag_id)
            self.drag_id = self.after(100, self.stop_drag)
            for p in self.pop_up_list:
                if p[1] == 1:
                    p[2].lift()
                    print(p[2])
                    p[2].geometry(f"+{p[3].winfo_rootx() + 65}+{p[3].winfo_rooty()}")

    def stop_drag(self):
        self.drag_id = ''
        for p in self.pop_up_list:
            if p[1] == 1:
                p[2].lift()
                p[2].geometry(f"+{p[3].winfo_rootx() + 65}+{p[3].winfo_rooty()}")

    def toggle_button_pop_ups(self, ndex, btn):
        p = self.pop_up_list
        if p[ndex][1] == 0:
            p[ndex][1] = 1
            p[ndex][2] = tk.Toplevel(self)

            n = id(p[ndex][2])

            tree_view = ttk.Treeview(p[ndex][2], columns=("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"),
                                     show="headings", height=14)
            tree_view.column("# 1", width=90, anchor=tk.CENTER)
            tree_view.heading("# 1", text="something")
            tree_view.column("# 2", width=90, anchor=tk.CENTER)
            tree_view.heading("# 2", text="something 2")
            tree_view.column("# 3", width=90, anchor=tk.CENTER)
            tree_view.heading("# 3", text="something 3")
            tree_view.column("# 4", width=90, anchor=tk.CENTER)
            tree_view.heading("# 4", text="something 4")
            tree_view.grid(column=2, row=2)
            p[ndex][2].overrideredirect(1)
            p[ndex][2].geometry(f"+{btn.winfo_rootx() + 65}+{btn.winfo_rooty()}")
        else:
            p[ndex][1] = 0
            p[ndex][2].destroy()
            p[ndex][2] = None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().mainloop()
```

Comment: I still think you should use frames or labels to pull this off instead of toplevel windows. Then you would not need to deal with resizing or moving issues. I also see that since you added the treeviews they no longer move with the window.

Comment: What is `n = id(p[ndex][2])` and why are you using global in a class. One of the major benefits of using class it to avoid global.

Comment: You also need to clarify in what way the resizing of the "parent" window should affect the size of the `Toplevel` (or whatever) windows.

Comment: oops, I added the wrong code, let me fix it.

Comment: When you say you want to resize the toplevel windows exactly what do you mean. What is happening to the main window that requires the toplevel windows to change size. And exactly how much change do you need to happen to them?

Comment: I want that when I resize the main window, the toplevel windows also get resize at a one to one ratio.

Comment: A resize event handler function attached to the main window could access its attributes via `event.widget.xxx` — so you could use that mechanism to access a list of `Toplevel` windows that the `Main` class created (and then resize them as desired).